# problems viewing PDF report created in java on ipad via safari

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, safari, frameset

I am creating a PDF report using Java. It opens in a pop-up box and displays well in all browsers except in Safari on iPad. Here, the pop-up pdf-page shows until the screen is there and then I don't see my data and I cant scroll down. However it works fine when I open it from a PC.

I am using Frame set in HTML. I saw some suggestions saying the frameset does not work on mobile iOS devices for may pages as scrolling cannot be done using frame set.

How can I write the below code using iFrame?

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" onLoad="NN623();reloadPDFImageKludge();TERalert();" frameborder="no">
        <frame noresize src="/messages/please_wait_report_pdf.jsp" name="<%= CreatePleaseWait.getDummyFrameName() %>">
        <frame noresize src="/blank.html" name="<%= CreatePleaseWait.getChildWindowName() %>">  
</frameset>
```

Comment: Could be a font issue. Maybe do some research into what fonts are available on the iPad

Comment: Are you using JAVA or JavaScript to create the PDF?

Comment: Could you post code? I helps understanding your question better.

Comment: And probably a sample PDF.

Comment: @Mikael Hellman This is the code i am using ,                                                                      <frameset rows="100%,*" onLoad="NN623();reloadPDFImageKludge();TERalert();" frameborder="no">
     <frame noresize src="/messages/please_wait_report_pdf.jsp" name="<%= CreatePleaseWait.getDummyFrameName() %>">
     <frame noresize src="/blank.html" name="<%= CreatePleaseWait.getChildWindowName() %>"> 
</frameset>

Comment: Please update your question with the .

Comment: @JasonAller I am using Java for creating PDf

Comment: I got it solved by putting the target=_top; in the form which gives the top most frame as your page